# Layout folder not showing in @drawable

Tags: android, listview

This is my file gradient_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#f1f1f2"
        android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
        android:endColor="#cfcfcf"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

I cant see it in the @drawable

```
  <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
```

I am a newbie please tell me what I have done incorrect.
This is my list selector that the item code is inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

Comment: is your gradient_bg file in drawable folder?

Comment: Its in the layout folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the gradient_bg xml file inside the drawable folder of your android application project and you will be able to access it.